# How many private variables are too many? Capsulizing classes? Class Practices?

Tags: python, class

Okay so i am currently working on an inhouse statistics package for python, its mainly geared towards a combination of working with arcgis geoprocessor, for modeling comparasion and tools.

Anyways, so i have a single class, that calculates statistics. Lets just call it Stats. Now my Stats class, is getting to the point of being very large. It uses statistics calculated by other statistics, to calculate other statistics sets, etc etc. This leads to alot of private variables, that are kept simply to prevent recalculation. however there is certain ones, while used quite frequintly they are often only used by one or two key subsections of functionality. (e.g. summation of matrix diagonals, and probabilities). However its starting to become a major eyeesore, and i feel as if i am doing this terribly wrong.

So is this bad?

I was recommended by a coworker, to simply start putting core and common functionality togther, in the main class, then simply having capsules, that take a reference to the main class, and simply do what ever functionality they need to within themselves. E.g. for calculating accuracy of model predictions, i would create a capsule, who simply takes a reference to the parent, and it will offload all of the calculations needed, for model predictions.

Is something like this really a good idea? Is there a better way? Right now i have over a dozen different sub statistics that are dumped to a text file to make a smallish report. The code base is growing, and i would just love it if i could start splitting up more and more of my python classes. I am just not sure really what the best way about doing stuff like this is.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of solutions. One would be to simply store values in an array with an enum like so:

```
StatisticType = enum('AveragePerDay','MedianPerDay'...)
```

Another would be to use a inheritance like so:

```
class StatisticBase
....
class AveragePerDay ( StatisticBase )
...
class MedianPerDay ( StatisticBase )
...
```

There is no hard and fast rule on "too many", however a guideline is that if the list of fields, properties, and methods when collapsed, is longer than a single screen full, it's probably too big.

Comment: The question is about Python, not C#.

Comment: That is my mistake. However, the principles are the same and the structures are similar in Python. However, I'll adjust.

Comment: Maybe i should have said that language does not really matter. Its more of a general class design topic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a class for each statistic you need to compute and when of the statistics requires other, just pass an instance of the latter to the computing method? However, there is little known about your code and required functionalities. Maybe you could describe in a broader fashion, what kind of statistics you need calculate and how they depend on each other?

Anyway, if I had to count certain statistics, I would instantly turn to creating separate class for each of them. I did once, when I was writing code statistics library for python. Every statistic, like how many times class is inherited or how often function was called, was a separate class. This way each of them was simple, however I didn't need to use any of them in the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common anti-pattern for a class to become "too fat" (have too much functionality and related state), and while this is commonly observed about "base classes" (whence the "fat base class" monicker for the anti-pattern), it can really happen without any inheritance involved.

Many design patterns (DPs for short_ can help you re-factor your code to whittle down the large, untestable, unmaintainable "fat class" to a nice package of cooperating classes (which can be used through "Facade" DPs for simplicity): consider, for example, State, Strategy, Memento, Proxy.

You could attack this problem directly, but I think, especially since you mention in a comment that you're looking at it as a general class design topic, it may offer you a good opportunity to dig into the very useful field of design patterns, and especially "refactoring to patterns" (Fowler's book by that title is excellent, though it doesn't touch on Python-specific issues).

Specifically, I believe you'll be focusing mostly on a few Structural and Behavioral patterns (since I don't think you have much need for Creational ones for this use case, except maybe "lazy initialization" of some of your expensive-to-compute state that's only needed in certain cases -- see [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list) for a pretty exhaustive listing of DPs, with classification and links for further explanations of each).

Comment: Personally i find design patterns to be painful, and go far far over the top. While sure, those design patterns are a good idea. However the overhead and time spent to actually make those classes and system fall within the definition of the design pattern leads to alot of headaches. I know i will get flamed for this comment, however i just fail to see the use of design patterns in a functional language.

Comment: I think you just haven't read the right essays, e.g. http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~antoy/flp/patterns/ , and books, e.g. http://books.google.com/books?id=MS2f1AATHIoC&dq=functional+design+patterns&printsec=frontcover&source=in&hl=en&ei=Zt6KS5yKIpSwsgOh4o2GAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=13&ved=0CD8Q6AEwDA#v=onepage&q=functional%20design%20patterns&f=false .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about best practices you might want to check out pylint (http://www.logilab.org/857).  It has many good suggestions about code style including ones relating to how many private variables in a class.